# Basic var misunderstanding

Tags: javascript

I have created this:

```
var where = function(){
  sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition()
}
console.log(where);

if (where()<=0){
  var playMan = sym.getSymbol("Man").play();
} else {
  var playMan = sym.getSymbol("Man").playReverse();
}
```

This is for Edge Animate hence all the syms. I am trying to access the timeline of symbol Man, then if it is at 0 play it. But it isnt working and the reason, I think, is that I have an incomplete understanding of how a var works. In my mind I am giving the variable 'where' the value of the timeline position of symbol 'Man'. In reality the console is just telling me I have a function there, not the value of the answer. I have run into this before and feel if I can crack it I will be a much better human being.

So if anyone can explain in baby-language what I am misunderstanding I would be grateful.

Thanks

S

Comment: `where` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think you want `return sym.getSymbol...`

Comment: and `playMan` is declared inside a block, it will not be accessible anywhere

Comment: Putting Curly braces on new lines hurts my eyes in JavaScript :[ On another note, as sje397 mentions, the `.getPosition()` is only available within the scope of the function.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use 'where' as a variable / function name. But perhaps that's just me.

Comment: @Ishank Javascript does *not* have block scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var where = function () { ... };
```

and

```
function where() { ... }
```

are essentially synonymous here. So, `where` is a function. You are calling that function here:

```
if (where()<=0)
```

However, the function does not `return` anything. You need to `return` the value from it, not just call `sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition()` inside it.

That, or don't make it a function:

```
var where = sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition();
if (where <= 0) ...
```

The value will only be checked and assigned once in this case, instead of updated every time you call `where()`.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that just by having
 `sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition()`
the function is getting the value, but just not placing it anywhere accessible to me until I return it?

Comment: Exactly. The value is retrieved and immediately discarded, because you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: The first option people suggested, returning the value in the function, does not work sadly. But `var where = sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition();` seems to work fine

Comment: Returning the value should work just fine as well, you'd have to provide a test case to show that it does not. However, if you're just using the variable once there, there's probably no need for a function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var where = function()
{
    return sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition();
};
```

Your code wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var where = function() {
      return sym.getSymbol("Man").getPosition()
    }
    console.log(where);

    if(where()<=0) {
      var playMan = sym.getSymbol("Man").play();
    } else {
      var playMan = sym.getSymbol("Man").playReverse();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, getPosition returns the value of the timeline in milliseconds